# CRM 2011 adding a dialog button to the ribbon

Tags: dialog, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have just created a Ribbon button and pointed it to a webresource js. However my code doesnt seem to launch my dialog. Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

```
function TestRibbon(sLeadID) 
{
var DialogGUID = "6D128DF9-F51A-4D97-912D-C5A1FA4CEAFB";
var serverUrl = "https://xxx.xxx.co.uk:444/";
serverUrl = serverUrl + "cs/dialog/rundialog.aspx?DialogId=" + "{" + DialogGUID + "}" +    "&EntityName=lead&ObjectId=" + sLeadID;
PopupCenter(serverUrl, "mywindow", 400, 400);
window.location.reload(true);
 }

function PopupCenter(pageURL, title, w, h) {
var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
var targetWin = window.showModalDialog(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no,     directories=no,   status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server URL is static. Use this code that generates URL dynamically, also with new release we figured out that URL with `status=no` is not opening correctly, so we started to use `status: no` and it became to work as expected. See the following code:

```
function TestRibbon(sLeadID) {
    var DialogGUID = "6D128DF9-F51A-4D97-912D-C5A1FA4CEAFB";
    // Get the CRM URL 
    var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();

    // Cater for URL differences between onpremise and online 
    if (serverUrl.match(/\/$/)) {
        serverUrl = serverUrl.substring(0, serverUrl.length - 1);
    }

    serverUrl = serverUrl + "/cs/dialog/rundialog.aspx?DialogId=" + "%7b" + DialogGUID + "%7d" + "&EntityName=lead&ObjectId=" + sLeadID;
    PopupCenter(serverUrl, "mywindow", 600, 500);
    window.location.reload();
}

function PopupCenter(pageUrl, title, w, h) {
    var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
    var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
    window.showModalDialog(pageUrl, title, 'status:no; scroll:no; resizable:no; dialogWidth: ' + w + 'px; dialogHeight: ' + h + 'px; dialogTop: ' + top + 'px; dialogLeft: ' + left + 'px;');
}
```

During investigation found [this post](http://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/140652-create-a-dialog-short-cut-ribbon-button) for [Ribbon Workbench for CRM 2011 Solution](http://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/80806-download-ribbon-workbench-for-crm-2011)

Comment: i get this "The URL you used to start the dialog is incorrect. Add a correct URL and try again."

Comment: This code works on my instance. Verify that you correct dialog Id and lead Id passed to the function,
if you have this button only on form you can change first few rows of function TestRibbon to 
`function TestRibbon() {
    var DialogGUID = "6D128DF9-F51A-4D97-912D-C5A1FA4CEAFB";
     sLeadID = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
    // Get the CRM URL ...`

Comment: That change of code worked. Am i right in thinking if the button is on form to use the updated GET the CRM, and if its on a homepage use the above code?

Comment: The difference beetwen those two is that in updated code I get sLeadID from the form Xrm object - it is easy: `sLeadID = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId()`. On Homepage you should pass selected item Id from the Ribbon button to code. If you are using [Ribbon Workbench Solution](http://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/80806-download-ribbon-workbench-for-crm-2011) you must create command with parameters to identify which entity is selected now.
I've found interesting [post](http://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/140652-create-a-dialog-short-cut-ribbon-button).